# codeigniter datamapper do action everytime after save

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

does codeigniter's datamapper has some lifecycle callbacks like in doctrine? I want to performe some action everytime datamapper saves the object, how can i do that in datamapper

Comment: No I don't think callbacks are supported. Another ORM that does support them is php-activerecord http://getsparks.org/packages/php-activerecord/versions/HEAD/show

Answer (score 0):

No, Datamapper doesn't support callback, however I can propose to create own by overiding the `save` method in your model, as follows:

```
    class YourModelName extends DataMapper {

      // ...

      public function save($object = '', $related_field = ''){

        // put before save callback here

        parent::save($object, $related_field);

        // put after save callback here
      }
    }
```